# I am using Django 1.8 after installing django redux 2.2 it started showing error Django.urls not found before installing redux it was working fine

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-1.8, django-email

ModuleNotFoundError at /

No module named 'django.urls'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpL5E.png)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use django-redux 2.0 with django version less than 1.11. Quote from django-redux [changelog](https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/blob/master/CHANGELOG):

> Version 2.0, 05 December, 2017
>   * BACKWARDS-INCOMPATIBLE CHANGE: Remove support for Django < 1.11.

You need to install previous version to use it with django 1.8:

```
pip install django-registration-redux==1.8
```